# rails 3.2.1 using has_secure_password have shown the message "table xxx has no column named password"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, activerecord

I am a newbie using rails, and I have been trying to build some tests against a controller whose model uses has_secure_password. Follow the test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControolerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @dados_user = {
      full_name: "Fulano",
      bio: "lorem ipsun lorum lorem ipsun lorum lorem ipsun lorum",
      location: "Brazil",
      email: "fulano@gmail.com",
      password: "123456",
      password_confirmation: "123456"
    }    
  end

  test "Cria usuário banco" do
    assert_difference('User.count') do
      post :create, user: @dados_user
    end
  end
end
```

When I ran the test, I received the following error message:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: table users has no column
 named password: INSERT INTO "users" ("full_name", "email", "password", "locatio
n", "bio", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") ...

The model's code is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :reviews, :dependent => :destroy

  scope :confirmed, where('confirmed_at IS NOT NULL')

  has_secure_password  
  attr_accessible :bio, :email, :full_name, :location, :password,
    :password_confirmation

  validates_presence_of :email, :full_name, :location
  validates_length_of :bio, :minimum => 30, :allow_blank => false
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[^@]+@([^@\.]+\.)+[^@\.]+\z/
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  before_create :generate_token

  def generate_token
    self.confirmation_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def confirm!
    return if confirmed?

    self.confirmed_at = Time.current
    self.confirmation_token = ''
    save!
  end

  def confirmed?
    confirmed_at.present?
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    confirmed.find_by_email(email).try(:authenticate, password)
  end
end
```

Could someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

P.S: Follow the migration code

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :full_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password
      t.string :location
      t.text :bio

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email, :unique => true
  end
end
```

---

The migration below was made regarding of the use of has_secure_password

```
class RenamePasswordOnUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    rename_column :users, :password, :password_digest
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

---

```
class AddConfirmationFieldsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: What does your migration file look like?  Have you tried rolling back and then re-running your migration? ...can you post your create_users migration?  That may shed some light on this...

Comment: I dropped and recreated all databases, and I ran rake db:migrate again, with no success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all good.  However you have to also run rake:db:test:prepare.  Running rake:db:migrate sets up your development database but it doesn't set up your test DB.

So, run:

```
rake:db:test:prepare
```

and you should find you no longer get that error.

Comment: I got the same error again. I think that the test environment didn't understand the has_secure_password.